# How can i rotate a circle?

Tags: android

i want to rotate this circle clockwise.

```
RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(0, 0, 70,Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
paint.setShader(gradient);
            canvas.save();

            canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2, 40, paint);
canvas.rotate()
canvas.restore();
```

Above code not working. It is not rotating why?

Answer (score 0):

Rotate **before** drawing on the canvas:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(degrees);
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

You can compare the operation with drawing on an actual physical canvas, first you rotate (`rotate`) it, then draw (`drawCircle`) on it, and lastly rotate it back again (`restore`).